# How to correctly implement a quaternion camera in modern opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, quaternions

I am trying to create a uvn quaternion based camera in opengl, having used a variety of tutorials listed below, and having read up on quaternions and axis angle rotation. I am left with a peculiar bug which I cannot seem to fix.

Basically the camera seems to work fine up until the camera is rotated approx 45 degrees from +z at this point tilting the camera up or down seems to tilt the camera around its target axis, turning the up vector.

By the time the camera faces along -z tilting up or down gives the illusion of the opposite, up tilts down and down tilts up.

I have seen other implementations suggesting the use of a non uvn system where quaternions are accumulated into one which describes the current orientation as a delta from some arbitrary start angle. This sounds great however I can't seem to work out exactly how I would implement this, specifically the conversion from  this to a view matrix.

Elsewhere on SO I read about splitting the rotation into two quaternions that represent the yaw and pitch separately but I'm not convinced that this is the cause of the problem since in this context, correct me if I am wrong but my understanding is that the order in which you apply the two rotations does not matter.

Relevant Source Code Snippets:

Quarternion Operations

```
Quaternion<TValue> conjugate() const{
            return Quaternion({ { -m_values[X], -m_values[Y], -m_values[Z], m_values[W] } });
};

Quaternion<TValue>& operator*=(const Quaternion<TValue>& rhs) {
        TValue x, y, z, w;
            w = rhs[W] * m_values[W] - rhs[X] * m_values[X] - rhs[Y] * m_values[Y] - rhs[Z] * m_values[Z];
            x = rhs[W] * m_values[X] + rhs[X] * m_values[W] - rhs[Y] * m_values[Z] + rhs[Z] * m_values[Y];
            y = rhs[W] * m_values[Y] + rhs[X] * m_values[Z] + rhs[Y] * m_values[W] - rhs[Z] * m_values[X];
            z = rhs[W] * m_values[Z] - rhs[X] * m_values[Y] + rhs[Y] * m_values[X] + rhs[Z] * m_values[W];          

            m_values[X] = x;
            m_values[Y] = y;
            m_values[Z] = z;
            m_values[W] = w;
            return *this;
};
static Quaternion<TValue> rotation(Vector<3, TValue> axis, TValue angle){
        float x, y, z, w;
        TValue halfTheta = angle / 2.0f;
        TValue sinHalfTheta = sin(halfTheta);
        return Quaternion<TValue>({ { axis[X] * sinHalfTheta, axis[Y] * sinHalfTheta, axis[Z] * sinHalfTheta, cos(halfTheta) } });
};
```

Vector Rotation Operation

```
Vector<dimensions, TValue> rotate(const Vector<3, TValue> axis, float angle){
        Quaternion<TValue> R = Quaternion<TValue>::rotation(axis, angle);
        Quaternion<TValue> V = (*this);
        Vector<dimensions, TValue> result = R * V * R.conjugate();
        return result;
}
```

Camera Methods

```
Camera::Camera(Vector<2, int> windowSize, float fov, float near, float far):
m_uvn(Matrix<4, float>::identity()),
m_translation(Matrix<4, float>::identity()),
m_ar(windowSize[Dimensions::X] / (float)windowSize[Dimensions::Y]),
m_fov(fov),
m_near(near),
m_far(far),
m_position(),
m_forward({ { 0, 0, 1 } }),
m_up({ { 0, 1, 0 } })
{
    setViewMatrix(Matrix<4, float>::identity());
    setProjectionMatrix(Matrix<4, float>::perspective(m_ar, m_near, m_far, m_fov));
};

Matrix<4, float> Camera::getVPMatrix() const{
    return m_vp;
};

const Vector<3, float> Camera::globalY = Vector<3, float>({ { 0, 1, 0 } });

void Camera::setProjectionMatrix(const Matrix<4, float> p){
    m_projection = p;
    m_vp = m_projection * m_view;
};

void Camera::setViewMatrix(const Matrix<4, float> v){
    m_view = v;
    m_vp = m_projection * m_view;
};

void Camera::setTranslationMatrix(const Matrix<4, float> t){
    m_translation = t;
    setViewMatrix(m_uvn * m_translation);
}

void Camera::setPosition(Vector<3, float> position){
    if (position != m_position){
        m_position = position;
        setTranslationMatrix(Matrix<4, float>::translation(-position));
    }
};

void Camera::moveForward(float ammount){
    setPosition(m_position + (m_forward * ammount));
}

void Camera::moveRight(float ammount){
    setPosition(m_position + (getRight() * ammount));
}

void Camera::moveUp(float ammount){
    setPosition(m_position + (m_up * ammount));
}

void Camera::setLookAt(Vector<3, float> target, Vector<3, float> up){
    Vector<3, float> newUp = up.normalize();
    Vector<3, float> newForward = target.normalize();
    if (newUp != m_up || newForward != m_forward){
        m_up = newUp;
        m_forward = newForward;

        Vector<3, float> newLeft = getLeft();
        m_up = newLeft * m_forward;

        m_uvn = generateUVN();
        setViewMatrix(m_uvn * m_translation);
    }
};

void Camera::rotateX(float angle){
    Vector<3, float> hAxis = (globalY * m_forward).normalize();
    m_forward = m_forward.rotate(hAxis, angle).normalize();
    m_up = (m_forward * hAxis).normalize();

    m_uvn = generateUVN();
    setViewMatrix(m_translation * m_uvn);
}

void Camera::rotateY(float angle){
    Vector<3, float> hAxis = (globalY * m_forward).normalize();
    m_forward = m_forward.rotate(globalY, angle).normalize();
    m_up = (m_forward * hAxis).normalize();

    m_uvn = generateUVN();
    setViewMatrix(m_translation * m_uvn);
}

Vector<3, float> Camera::getRight(){
    return (m_forward * m_up).normalize();
}

Vector <3, float> Camera::getLeft(){
    return (m_up * m_forward).normalize();
}
```

};

I am guessing that the problem is in either my implementation of a quaternion or the way I am using it, but due to the complex nature of the system I cannot seem to pin down the problem any further than that. Due to the weird bugs being experienced I am unsure if there is just something wrong with the way I am trying to implement the camera?

Tutorials

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Aw1PDu33PI
- http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-simple-quaternion-based-camera-r1997

Quarternion/Vector Math

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product
- http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial13/tutorial13.html
- http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/index.htm

Comment: I think that the best thing to do is to break down your function process--try to write a 1:1 mapping of the mathematical process vs. the code and compare the documentation to the math.

Comment: This question would require a way too long answer (as far as I can see it - I can't because of all the code). You should provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve not your whole implementation. Try to pin the error down and then ask for help here.

Comment: Compare your implementation's output to [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html) or [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00174.html).

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still a relevant topic so I'll give some pointers. The thing to remember is a quaternion is a 3D map. Unit, and to a lesser degree Pure, quaternions provide a consistent way to say this rotation is this value. The benefits of this over the Euler angles are they attempt to reconstruct orientation from  rotation about some axis where as the quaternion directly correlates to the orientation and *can* avoid gimbal lock

Specifically for a quaternion camera let Q{1,0,0,0} where w=1, the corresponding matrix to this quaternion is the identity matrix. There for any valid unit quaternion when decomposed into a 3x3 matrix gives you the (usually) world space rotation of the camera. However you don't even need that because you can define your camera space so that say X{1,0,0} Y{0,1,0} Z{0,0,-1} then multiply these unit axes by your cameras orientation quaternion and the resulting vector is the transformed unit vector. These then create your right up and front vectors which can be used to build the 3x3 rotation of the view transform.

Moving the camera should be relatively straight forward at that point. The linear movement vectors can be easily reconstructed and applied to the camera position and the angular movement can be achieved by multiplying the the camera quaternion with the direction which is the normal of the corresponding plane in which the rotation happens. For example, turning left and right is a rotation that happens in there XZ plane there for the Y vector{as a unit quaternion not a pure quaternion} would be multiplied with the camera quaternion producing the desired rotational effect